# Unity autocomplete in Visual Studio Code works but in an unexpected way

Tags: unity-game-engine, autocomplete

I would like Visual Studio to autocomplete code in this way
[desired autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNK1N.png)

Unfortunately, autocompletion is working in this way [current autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E3xX.png)

I'm on macOS Monterey 12.4, MacMini M1 2020.
Visual Studio Code Version 1.68.1 (Universal)
Unity Version 2020.3.30f1 Personal
Extensions currently enabled [enabled extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUSWu.png)

Please point me in the right direction to fix it.
Thank you!

Comment: Visual studio and visual studio code are not the same product.

Comment: Maybe you should remove these Unityxxxx extensions